# Cannot load file or asembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I an old program, which uses Entity Framework Core 2.2.6 to access a MS-SQL database. Now I would like to add some tests to this program, which I would prefer to do using the  InMemory package for EFCore.

I have a very simple method for getting data, which works in the actual program, but when I try to call it with an InMemory database, I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>         ----> System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Now it seems to expect `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` version 3.1.0. However, I never asked it to install that. In fact I am trying to keep all EFCore versions <=2.2.6, as the program is created in the .NET Framework. The only difference I can find is that my test assembly seems to use the `app.config` file for package configuration, whereas my remaining assemblies are using a file called `packages.config`. This is not something I have done intentionally, it just autoconfigured it, when I was installing Nuget packages. Here is the difference between the content of the two:

**app.config**

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

**packages.config**

```
<package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net47" />
```

Does anyone know if this error is related to the difference between using `app.config` and `packages.config`, or am I on a wild goose chase? And if so, what else can be causing this error and how do I force it to use the 2.2.0 version of the package, like the other assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change that `app.config` block to:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Although I would recommend deleting this block, removing the package and re-adding it.

`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` `3.1.0` targets `netstandard2.0`, so you could possibly be able to use that, in which case you can keep your `app.config` file as it is and upgrade the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` explicitly in your `packages.config` file.

Comment: I would rather nok go into the EFCore 3.x.x. Even if they claim that they fixed the .NET Standard support, I have still had nothing but trouble, when using it with .NET Framework. Your suggestion removed to first error, but it keeps chaining similar errors.